# Powershell copy special public folder, paste as is. Windows 10

Tags: powershell, copy

I'm using Windows 10 Powershell (version 6.2.2) scripts to customise Windows 10 installations.

I am trying to copy special public folders, Public Downloads, Public Documents, Public Music, ... to another drive.

With all my attempts, I can't transfer or preserve the displayed special folder name, instead I "real" folder name, like Downloads, Music, not Public Music for instance.

I have been using,

`Copy-Item -Path 'C:\Users\Public\Music' -Destination 'D:\Users\Public'`

This will copy,

C:\Users\Public\Public Music

But will yield,

D:\Users\Public\Music

Rather than

D:\Users\Public\Public Music

What am I missing? Performing a manual copy, will yield the folder with it's displayed name.

Any hint is appreciated.

Thanks and regards,

- njc

Answer (score 0):

Copy has done exactly what you have asked it has taken:
 `'C:\Users\Public\Music'` and placed it in `'D:\Users\Public'`
Resulting in a final Path of `D:\Users\Public\Music`

If you desire the Public Music to be final destination you need to specify as such try this:

```
Copy-Item -Path 'C:\Users\Public\Public Music' -Destination 'D:\Users\Public'
```

If you need the items inside that folder to copy as well make sure to pass the recursive flag:

```
Copy-Item -Path 'C:\Users\Public\Public Music -Destination 'D:\Users\Public' -Recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long while, like a year ago, while I'm logged on, I thought I'd post my solution, in case anyone else has a similar problem.

```
Robocopy.exe /copyall 'C:\Users\Public\Videos' 'D:\Users\Public\Videos' | Out-Null

if ($LastExitCode -ne 1) {
    # throw exception
}
```

This will copy the source, 'C:\Users\Public\Public Videos', and paste it as, 'D:\Users\Public\Public Videos'.

Thanks and regards,
njc